# Apply style to xml attribute value

Tags: css, xml, xslt

I am trying applying style to the below  XML code for the Label attribute

```
<NavItem Description="" id="client1" Label="My Information"  SequenceNumber="3" ></NavItem>
```

Here is the XSL Code

```
<h3 title="{@Description}">
  <a href="#">
    <img src="{$imgSrc}" />
    <xsl:value-of select="@Label"/>
  </a>
```

With the above XSLT code I am getting value from label as an output but I don't no how to apply CSS to the Label.

Kindly help me for

Thanks & Regards
Mahadevan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap the value in an HTML element, e.g.

```
<span class="label"><xsl:value-of select="@Label"/></span>
```

Then you can add a suitable `link` element (referring to an external CSS stylesheet), or a `style` element in the `head` part, using normal CSS, e.g.

```
<style>
.label { font-size: 80%; font-family: Calibri, sans-serif }
</style>
```

As a less structured approach, sometimes suitable in simplest cases, you could alternative use a CSS style sheet embedded in a `style` attribute:

```
<span style="font-size: 80%"><xsl:value-of select="@Label"/></span>
```

Comment: Thanks for the earliest reply. However if I have two XML code , what should i do to change background colour                       <NavItem Description="" id="client1" Label="My Information"  SequenceNumber="3" ></NavItem>
<NavItem Description="" id="client2" Label="My Client"  SequenceNumber="3" ></NavItem>

Comment: If you want to change the background for both of them, you could do as outlined in the first part of my answer, just with the `style` element containing e.g. `.label { background: yellow }`. If you want the labels from the two elements to have different backgrounds, the simplest way is to use `id` instead of `class`, emitting a copy of the XML `id` attribute into the HTML code and using (in CSS) `id` selectors like `#client1` and `#client2`.

Answer (score 0):

A simple "Hello XSLT" example:
hello.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <?xml-stylesheet href="hello.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
  <page>
   <title>Hello</title>
   <content>Here is some content</content>
   <comment>Written by DKS.</comment>
</page>
```

Wanted result document

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd">
 <html>
   <head>
     <title>Hello</title>
   </head>
   <body bgcolor="#ffffff">
     <h1 align="center">Hello</h1>
     <p align="center"> Here is some content</p>
     <hr><i>Written by DKS</i>
   </body>
 </html>
```

The XSLT Stylesheet

hello.xslt

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>                
 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

 <xsl:template match="page">
    <html> 
      <head> 
        <title> <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
      </title>
     </head>
     <body bgcolor="#ffffff">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
     </body>
    </html>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="title">
    <h1 align="center"> <xsl:apply-templates/>  </h1>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="content">
    <p align="center"> <xsl:apply-templates/> </p>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="comment">
    <hr/> <i><xsl:apply-templates/> </i>
   </xsl:template>
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

For more information. See here ..http://edutechwiki.unige.ch/en/XSLT_Tutorial_-_Basics

Update:

To link the XML file to the CSS, you use this code:

Then write your css code inside yourstyle.css :
eg:

```
label {
display: block;
font-weight: bold;
margin: 5px;
width: 225px;
text-align: right;
background: #dedede;
}
```

Comment: The question asked how to apply CSS. The answer has no CSS.

Comment: I thought formatting XML with CSS is not the most common method. Because W3C recommends using XSLT instead. I will update the answer using CSS.

Comment: XSLT is really a transformation language, not a style sheet language. I have no idea of what W3C recommendation you are referring to. And this is about styling the HTML produced with XSLT, not about styling XML. And the W3C surely recommends using CSS rather than presentational HTML elements and attributes (such as `align`) for styling HTML documents.